# Extraction of rows which have a value > 50

Tags: perl, shell

How to select those lines which have a value < 10 value from a large matrix of 21 columns and 150 rows.eg.

```
miRNameIDs  degradome   AGO     LKM......till 21
osa-miR159a      0       42      42
osa-miR396e      0        7       9
vun-miR156a     121      77       4
ppt-miR156a     12        7       4
gma-miR6300     118       2       0
bna-miR156a      0        114     48
gma-miR156k      0        46       1
osa-miR1882e     0        7        0
.
.
.
```

Desired output is:-

```
miRNameIDs  degradome   AGO    LKM......till 21
vun-miR156a      121    77      4
gma-miR6300      118    2       0
bna-miR156a       0    114      48
.
.
.
till 150 rows
```

Comment: Why is the line `osa-miR159a      0       42      42` not included in the desired output? (It has a value 0 in column 2, which is less than 10)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -ane 'print if $. == 1 || grep {$_ > 50} @F[1..$#F]' file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `$. == 1`: Checks if the current line is line number 1.
- `grep {$_ > 50} @F[1..$#F]`: Looks at each entries from the array to see if it is greater than 50.
- `||`: Logical `OR` operator. If any of our above stated condition is true, it prints the line.

Comment: I'd give you a +1 if you'd explain the magic. Yes, **-lane** and **@F** can be googled .. but so could the original question, provided the answer was already known ...

Comment: @lexu Added an explanation for you and others seeking reference.